# NLog config in YAML format

Tags: yaml, nlog

I'm using NLog and want to store its configuration in YAML files instead of XML or JSON.

I have the working code (.NET 6) which works with the below YAML, except for the commented-out part.
It uses NetEscapades.Configuration.Yaml library to make YAML magic.

The question is about the "variable" elements which I'm unable to convert into YAML.

```
NLog:
  throwConfigExceptions: true
  internalLogToConsole: true
  
  # How to write this in YAML?
  #<variable name="var1" value="value1" />
  #<variable name="var2" value="value2" />
  
  targets:
    file:
      type: File
      fileName: someFilename.txt
      layout: layout
  rules:
  - logger: "*"
    minLevel: Trace
    maxLevel: Fatal
    writeTo: file
```

The C# code that setups logging in case someone is interested in it:

```
var host =
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddYamlFile(@"nlog.yml", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
        {
            ConfigurationServices.Register(host.Configuration, services);
        })
        .ConfigureLogging((host, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddNLog(host.Configuration);
        })
        .Build();
```

What I tried (and it didn't work):

```
variable: 
  - 
    name: "var1"
    value: "value1"
  - 
    name: "var2"
    value: "value2"



variable:
  - '@name': var1
    '@value': value1
  - '@name': var2
    '@value': value2



variable:
  - { '@attributes': { name: var1, value: value1 } }
  - { '@attributes': { name: var2, value: value2 } }
```

### Update

Thanks to Rolf Kristensen, this syntax is working:

```
variables:
  var1: value1
  var2: value2
```

Comment: Maybe use `variables:` instead of `variable:` ? See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json#extended-json-nlog-config-example

Comment: Doesn't work either. Getting one of these errors (depending on the specific variation):
NLog.NLogConfigurationException: 'Property 'value' has blank value, for element 'Variable' in section 'variables''
or
NLog.NLogConfigurationException: 'Property 'name' has blank value, for element 'variable' in section 'variables''

Comment: This works for me `variables: LogDirectory: ${basedir}` (Adding the necessary newlines). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/446

Comment: Yep, this one looks ok. Please post it as an answer, I will accept it.
Also, didn't find the link you posted despite searched for everywhere :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML configuration should work just like [JSON configuration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json#extended-json-nlog-config-example), so performing a JSON-to-YAML conversion should produce a working configuration.

Example with NLog variables:

```yaml
NLog:
  throwConfigExceptions: true
  variables:
    LogDirectory: "${basedir}"
  targets:
    logFile:
      type: File
      fileName: ${LogDirectory}/info.log
    logConsole:
      type: Console
  rules:
  - logger: "*"
    minLevel: Trace
    writeTo: logFile
  - logger: "*"
    minLevel: Warn
    writeTo: logConsole
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/446